# Continuous function on the unit circle must be $c\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a homework problem, so hints or rough outlines are strongly preferred to a full solution.

**Problem.** Let $C$ be the unit circle.  Suppose the continuous function $f : C \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on the unit circle satisfies $|f(z)| \leq M$ and $\left|\int_{C} f(z)\;dz\right| = 2\pi M$.  Show that $f(z) = c\bar{z}$ for some constant $c$ with modulus $|c| = M$.

I've been able to argue $|f(z)| = M$ for all $z \in C$ by assuming this is not the case and finding a contradiction using continuity, the given identity, and the $ML$-inequality.  This is clearly necessary, but may not be useful to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation that $|f(z)|=M$ is useful. From the equality we get, if $z=e^{it}$,
$$
f(z)=M\,e^{ig(t)},\quad g\in C([0,2\,\pi],\mathbb{R}),\quad g(0)=g(2\,\pi)\pmod {2\,\pi}
$$
and $$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ig(t)}e^{it}\,dt=2\,\pi\,e^{i\alpha}
$$
for some $\alpha\in[0,2\,\pi)$. From this
$$
\Re(e^{-i\alpha}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ig(t)}e^{it}\,dt)=\int_0^{2\pi}\Re(e^{i(g(t)+t-\alpha)})\,dt=2\,\pi.
$$
Deduce that
$$
\Re(e^{i(g(t)+t-\alpha)})=1\quad \forall t
$$
and that $g(t)+t-\alpha=0$ for all $t$. I hope I have not given too much detail.

Comment: This was very helpful and left me with some to verify for myself, but I believe I have a complete solution now. Thank you.

Comment: Well, $|f(z)|/M=1$ and $g(t)=\arg(f(e^{it}))$.

Comment: You can deduce $\Re(e^{i(g(t)+t-\alpha)})=1\quad \forall t$ without using the line above this. How is this line used in the proof?

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to write $$\left| \int_C f(z) dz \right| =\left| \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{it}) i e^{it} dt \right|=\left| \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{it}) e^{it} dt \right| \le \int_0^{2 \pi} \left| f(e^{it}) \right| dt \le 2 \pi M$$ then reason about when this can be an equality.

Comment: I followed Julián Aguirre's answer as it built on what I had already shown for myself.  I do see how the second inequality being an equality forces $|f(e^{it})| = M$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$.  I do not quite understand what the first inequality being an equality forces.  Would you be willing to elaborate on this?

Comment: It forces that the integrand, as a vector over $\mathbb{R}$, must always point to the same direction i.e. have constant argument.